# New GridField item on each page - SilverStripe

Tags: silverstripe

I am trying to use GridField to allow CMS users to add information (Mailing Lists) to an article of the same page type (Shows) but every new page that's created is already populated with information from previous articles.

I think it may have something to do with the way I've set up the relationships between the Shows page type and the Mailing List DataObject but I can't figure out what I need to do for every new show page to have it's own blank GridField as the mailing list isn't the same for every show...

I've tried many combinations of $has_one, $has_many & $many_many on the two files but nothing gets it working the way I need it to which is for every Show page to have it's own GridField (Mailing List)...

The code I have at the moment is:

**Shows.php**

```
private static $has_many = array(
    'MailingLists' => 'MailingList'
);
```

...

```
$config = GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor::create();

$gridField = new GridField('MailingList',
       'Shows Mailing List',
       new DataList('MailingList'),
       $config
);

$fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Content.MailingList', array(
     $gridField
));
```

**MailingList.php**

```
class MailingList extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'Title' => 'Varchar(25)',
        'Description' => 'Varchar(55)'
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'Shows' => 'Shows'
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this code

```
$gridField = new GridField('MailingList',
   'Shows Mailing List',
   new DataList('MailingList'),
   $config
);
```

you select all records in the MailingList table with `new DataList('MailingList')`, but you should use related list of records with `$this->MailingLists()`

```
$gridField = new GridField('MailingList',
   'Shows Mailing List',
   $this->MailingLists(),
   $config
);
```

Comment: Oh. My. God! I tried this the other day and got a server error which is why I reverted back to using new DataList()... Could you explain why it worked this time?? Does $this->MailingLists() link to the $has_many bit?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Yes `$this->MailingLists()` does link to the `$has_many` `MailingLists` relationship.

Comment: That's good to know, I must have tried using `$this->MailingLists()` while I had the relationship set as `$has_one` which is why it didn't work for me and I assumed that wasn't what the issue was. Thanks for clearing that up

Comment: @freemium a protip: set ss to dev mode to see the actual error message instead of the webservers server error page to ease up development. You might also need to tweak the display errors value on php.ini. That makes it easier to spot coding issues :). Or view the php error logs from the server directly.

Comment: @FinBoWa Thanks for the tip - since I asked this I've enabled SS logs so I can see what part of my code is breaking which is helpful. I'll enable dev mode as well, can never have too many safety catches!  :)